# Neural network to verify amex check digit

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import tensorflow as tf

    data = pd.read_csv("Amex.csv")

    data.head()

    X = data.iloc[:, :-1].values
    Y = data.iloc[:, -1].values

    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1234)

    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
    sc = StandardScaler()
    x_train = sc.fit_transform(x_train)
    x_test = sc.fit_transform(x_test)


    ann = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

    ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1000, activation='sigmoid'))
    ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1280, activation='sigmoid'))

    ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=10, activation='softmax'))
    ann.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    ann.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=200)

    print(ann.predict(sc.transform([[3,7,9,8,8,1,4,4,7,0,4,5,2,6]])))`
```

I have trained the model with an accuracy of 0.9994 The answer should be 1, but I get an array list

output

```
 [[8.7985291e-06 2.5825528e-04 2.8821041e-03 1.0145088e-04 1.5824498e-04   8.1912667e-06 1.9685100e-03 9.9447292e-01 6.3032545e-05 7.8425743e-05]]
```

Comment: Why would you use a neural net for this?  There is a well-documented and simple algorithm that can verify the check digit.  No modelling is needed.  99.94% accuracy is pretty good for a trained model.

Comment: @TimRoberts I assume this is a learning exercise.

Comment: What does your training data look like? Are they all 2D lists? Are you sure that the input data should be `[[3,7,9,8,8,1,4,4,7,0,4,5,2,6]]` instead of `[3,7,9,8,8,1,4,4,7,0,4,5,2,6]`?

Comment: @TimRoberts, I'm new to deep learning and this is a learning exercise

Comment: @Code-Apprentice. Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[3. 7. 9. 8. 8. 1. 4. 4. 7. 0. 4. 5. 2. 6.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Comment: Right, the array of 15 elements is a single sample, so the nested list is appropriate.

Comment: ok, I think that means my suggestion is incorrect. I don't know enough about tensorflow to do anything else but guess what might be your problem.

Comment: also, why do you expect the "answer" to be 1? What do you mean? Do you expect just an integer 1 or should it be a list of 1s?

Comment: You should study more Deep Learning, as this is just an array of probabilities output by the model, and an argmax should be applied to obtain a class index, very standard stuff.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I tried argmax and got the expected result. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Dr. Snoopy for the answer and @AlphaTK for confirming that the issue got resolved. Adding this comment into the answer section for the community benefit.

> This is just an array of probabilities output by the model and an
> argmax should be applied to obtain a class index.